# Xamarin License and choosing Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin and I am thinking of developing an application both in iOS and Android using Xamarin.forms.

I have looked through the Xamarin licenses but I am unsure if the free or community license includes Xamarin.forms or will I need a paid license to use Xamarin.forms.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because licensing is off-topic on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Xamarin.Forms is included in the community editions

> Does this mean no more Starter Edition?
>
> Yes. Visual Studio Community
>   and Xamarin Studio Community editions give many more developers the
>   ability to develop Xamarin apps without Starter’s limitations on size
>   or functionality.
>
> Can Xamarin.Forms apps be built from any Visual
>   Studio edition, including Community?
>
> Yes.

From [Xamarin FAQ](https://www.xamarin.com/faq)